# Calculating window handle from module file path gets wrong results

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-11-alexandria

In a 32-bit VCL Application in Windows 10 in Delphi 11 Alexandria, I am trying to get the window handle of a running main task from the task's module path:

```
type
  TFindWindowRec = record
  ModuleToFind: string;
  FoundHWnd: HWND;
end;

function EnumWindowsCallBack(aHandle: HWND; var FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  C_FileNameLength = 256;
var
  WinFileName: string;
  PID, hProcess: DWORD;
  Len: Byte;
begin
  Result := True;

  SetLength(WinFileName, C_FileNameLength);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(aHandle, PID);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, PID);
  Len := GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, PChar(WinFileName), C_FileNameLength);
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(WinFileName, Len);
    if SameText(WinFileName, FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := aHandle;
    end;
  end;
end;

var
  FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec;

function TformMain.GetmainWindowHandleFRomProcessPath(aProcessPath: string): HWND;
begin
  Result := 0;
  CodeSite.Send('TformMain.GetmainWindowHandleFRomProcessPath: aProcessPath', aProcessPath);
  FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind := aProcessPath;
  FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := 0;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsCallback, Integer(@FindWindowRec));
  if FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd;
    CodeSite.Send('TformMain.GetmainWindowHandleFRomProcessPath: Result', Result);
  end;
end;
```

When I do this with:

```
GetmainWindowHandleFRomProcessPath('c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe');
```

... then I get the correct window handle.

When I do this with:

```
GetmainWindowHandleFRomProcessPath('C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\bin\bds.exe');
```

... then I get a WRONG (non-existing) window handle!

Why is this happening? How do I get the correct window handle?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242380/discussion-on-question-by-user1580348-calculating-window-handle-from-module-file). Please don't update your question to include answers or to change the question itself. If you have an answer to provide, please post it as an answer below, and if you have a new question, you should ask a second question.

Comment: Comments are for requesting or providing clarification about questions and answer. They are and always have been subjection to routine deletion, and when useful information has surfaced, it should be edited into the question or answer. If you want to discuss site policies, this is not the space to do this. Consider asking a question on [meta]. However, the topic of comment deletion has been *extremely* well covered, and I would recommend doing some research before asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion with Remy and Andreas lead me to this successful working answer:

```
type
  TFindWindowRec = record
  ModuleToFind: string;
  FoundHWnd: HWND;
end;

// The `RzShellUtils` unit is from Ray Konopka's Signature Library available from GetIt:
function PathsAreSamePIDL(const Path1, Path2: string): Boolean;
begin
  var AIL1: PItemIdList;
  var AIL2: PItemIdList;
  RzShellUtils.ShellGetIdListFromPath(Path1, AIL1);
  RzShellUtils.ShellGetIdListFromPath(Path2, AIL2);
  var CompResult:= RzShellUtils.CompareAbsIdLists(AIL1, AIL2);
  Result := CompResult = 0;
end;

function EnumWindowsCallBack(aHandle: HWND; var FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec): BOOL; stdcall;
const
  C_FileNameLength = MAX_PATH;
  PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION = $1000;
var
  WinFileName: string;
  PID, hProcess: DWORD;
  Len: Byte;
begin
  Result := True;

  SetLength(WinFileName, C_FileNameLength);
  GetWindowThreadProcessId(aHandle, PID);
  hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, False, PID);
  Len := GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess, 0, PChar(WinFileName), C_FileNameLength);
  CloseHandle(hProcess);
  if Len > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(WinFileName, Len);
    //if SameText(WinFileName, FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind) then
    if PathsAreSamePIDL(WinFileName, FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind) then
    begin
      var IsVisible := IsWindowVisible(aHandle);
      if not IsVisible then EXIT;
      var IsOwned := GetWindow(aHandle, GW_OWNER) <> 0;
      if IsOwned then EXIT;
      var IsAppWindow := GetWindowLongPtr(aHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE) and WS_EX_APPWINDOW <> 0;
      if not IsAppWindow then EXIT;

      Result := False;
      FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := aHandle;
    end;
  end;
end;

function TformMain.GetMainWindowHandleFromProcessPath(aProcessPath: string): HWND;
var
  FindWindowRec: TFindWindowRec;
begin
  Result := 0;
  FindWindowRec.ModuleToFind := aProcessPath;
  FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd := 0;
  EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsCallback, LPARAM(@FindWindowRec));
  if FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := FindWindowRec.FoundHWnd;
  end;
end;
```

I don't understand why the person who moved the discussion to another page deleted the latest comments. Was there anything forbidden in those deleted comments?

Again: Thank you to Remy and Andreas!